# React google Login firing error on render and after sign in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

So, I am starting to use React-Google-Login to create a sign in button, I pretty much followed the documentation, but I am receiving 2 errors.

So, here is my code for now.

```
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';

const Login = ({ classes }) => {
  const onSuccess = (googleUser) => {
     console.log(googleUser);
  }
      return <GoogleLogin clientId="MYTOKEN.apps.googleusercontent.com" onSuccess={onSuccess} isSignedIn={true} />;
};
```

As soon my component renders, I receive this error

> Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
>       at google-login.js:274

but I am still able to see to button, and when I click it I receive this error when it finishes the action

> Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function
>       at google-login.js:312

So what are this errors about ? I am sure my token is right, and pretty much sure the configuration on google console is right as well.

How to solve it ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issues

Comment: @Sanjiv yes. I will add an response so you can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not well documented pretty much anywhere in the official documentation and I am not really sure this is the best approach for the problem, since many people haven't the same problem when following the documentation.

My solution was adding a callback error on the component itself:

```
<GoogleLogin clientId="MYTOKEN.apps.googleusercontent.com" onSuccess={onSuccess} onFailure={err => console.log('fail', err)} isSignedIn={true} />;
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was solved by enabling cookies. It seems that the GoogleLogin component requires cookies to function and that my chrome browser had been blocking it's attempts to access them.